# Build times take about 70 min from 3 minutes - with Angular7 upgrade

Tags: angular, tfs, angular-cli, tfsbuild, angular7

I was using Angular 5 & 6 for my app and deployment with Angular cli (ng build --prod) took not more than 4 minutes ever.

However, couple of months ago we migrated to Angular 7, with very poor build times (approximately 60 - 75 minutes on an average), and eventually fail. I realized the issue with memory outage on my build server with the build, which uses about 1.7 GB by default but needs almost double that after the upgrade.

I searched online to find an option to increase node memory and then execute the build, manual works fine, however creating a command to execute the request results in errors. Below is the details of my situation and error:

**Environment:**

Windows Server 2016 with 8 GB RAM (default is to increase memory on the server :))

**Application:**

Angular 7, Node.js 8.11.3

**Build:**

TFS, use node_modules/.bin/ng tool to execute ng build --prod command for building application

**Error:**

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

**What I tried:**

node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules.bin\ng build --prod

Unfortunately, i cannot execute this from a command step on TFS build server.

How can I fix this or execute the above fix in TFS build step.

Cheers,

K

Comment: Out of curiosity have you tried with a recent version of node?

Comment: @DaveNewton I have not, sorry, the latest seems to be 10.15.3, does it change anything on my build server wrt the error?

Comment: @DaveNewton I upgraded to node 10.15.3, however the build times remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had a similar issue and after these two steps Angular 7 build started to work again:

I updated the package.json file and added this into "scripts" section.

```
"build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build  --prod --aot"
```

Once that was done then on TFS build:

[image]